# Apache Proxy-server receives a POST request but converts to GET?

Tags: apache, post, https, get, reverse-proxy

I'm setting up Apache to front a backend server and issue a command line request to the Server. Apache receives the request as POST ( confirmed from the log), but the proxy-server converts it to a GET request. Any idea why this is happening? I have set up a simple reverse-proxy using Apache. Is there any special URL rewrite that needs to be done? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

shall you please share the code snippet.. And in case if you have already got the solution please do share the same also...

*not sure if the comment should have gone here but i dint have an otherwise option to put it elsewhere..*

Comment: Cannot share the code snippet. But there was an intermediate perl handler that had to be taken care of.